# How to get FQL to work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

This is a newbie question. I am unable to find an example (in HTML) to get started on Facebook's FQL API.

This is what I have currently:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=216492851715113&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    FB.init({
        appId: '216492851******',
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });
</script>

<script>
    FB.api(
    {
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'SELECT name, pic_small FROM user WHERE uid=me()'
    },
    function (response) {
        alert('Name is ' + response[0].name);
    }
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I am expecting to see my name display in an alert (because I am logged on to Facebook).

At first I think it wasn't working because I am using localhost, but I have already modify my Host file to match up the URL I provided to Facebook.

I am guessing this is a session issue because if I changed the query to use a hard coded ID:

```
'SELECT name, pic_small FROM user WHERE uid=696190859'
```

It would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20name,%20pic_small%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=696190859&format=JSON

or more specifically:

> query: 'SELECT%20name,pic_small%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=me()'

you need to make sure the url is encoded. See here:
http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Hopefully that works?

Comment: Thanks, I can't get the me() to work tho. I used "http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20name,%20pic_small%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=me()&format=JSON" and the result is an empty JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the user has authenticated with your application by calling the FB.login() or validate that they have already authenticated by calling FB.getLoginStatus().  Otherwise, me() won't exist as you are experiencing because they haven't authenticated.